# margin-bottom not working on divs

Tags: html, css, floating, margins

Can someone help me figure out why my margin-bottom rule within my mobile view media query is not working?

I have even added a class to clear the floats named `.clearer` but that isn't working either. All I want is for the left image to have a 30px margin below it on the mobile view.

Here is the page... http://www.haveaseatrentals.com/seat-yourself/

CSS rule from the mobile view's media query and the rule that I am using to clear the floats...

```
#seatYourselfLeft {margin-bottom: 30px; }
.clearer{clear:both; width:100%; height:0; display: block;}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your CSS for the image containers to `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: inline;`

This question has been asked before, and has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8782644/3781678

Comment: @AlexWilliams It worked for me on your site! You need to add `margin-bottom: 30px;` to `#seatYourselfLeft`, that is not present on your site.